# Routes has no parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I am new learning Laravel, I dont understand why my routes have no parameters like "id" ?
[image]

I created routes by doing :

```
Route::resource('/', 'PostsController');
```

Please can you help me ?

Comment: Use a different URI: `Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');`

Comment: Read about route in Laravel document. Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers and https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/laravel-routeresource-vs-routecontroller/

Comment: The *actual* documentation is at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing and https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your first argument with resource name like this:

```php
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
```

If you want to customize it:

```php
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController')->except([
    'index'
]);

Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('posts.index');
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much and thanks for all But it do not works  Route [show] not defined. (View: C:\wamp64\www\blog\resources\views\index.blade.php)

Comment: @JulienRnsNeo in your `index.blade.php` replace `route('show')` with `route('posts.show')`

Answer (score 3):

Put a name for your route to achieve your goal like this.

```
Route::resource('post', 'PostsController');
```

Comment: It works but I want to show my posts on root page :o

Comment: then you can call your root page like
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index');

Answer (score 0):

According to the Laravel docs:

By default, Route::resource will create the route parameters for your resource routes based on the "singularized" version of the resource name. You can easily override this on a per resource basis by passing parameters in the options array.

Try the below code. It's working for you.

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController', ['parameters' => [
    'posts' => 'id'
]]);
```